# Как мне кидать картинку с компа на Яндекс.Картинки и получать что на фото?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, яндекс-картинки

как мне кидать картинку с компа на https://yandex.ru/images/ и получать что на фото?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://yandex.ru/images/search?source=collections&rpt=imageview&url=https://canon-fan.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/small_image/moon.jpg'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
similar = soup.find_all('li', class_='cbir-similar__thumb')
for i in similar:
    print(f"https://yandex.ru{i.find('a').get('href')}\n")
```

не работает, bs4 выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Формирование результата запроса происходит динамически, и классы которые вы ищете, тоже. Для данной задачи лучше использовать библиотеку selenium, которая может эмулировать открытие браузера и ожидать результата поиска.

Comment: а как-то еще можно?

Comment: @ЕгорРокита расскажите более подробно, какой функционал планируется сделать. что конкретно вы хотите получить?

Comment: у меня есть папка с 1000фото, я хочу отправлять фото на сервер и получать к ним теги, по тегам сортировать по папкам